# Is it possible to create a function receiving an infinite amount of arguments of the same type (or at least a good amount) in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a function named "init" that receives a single argument of a class named "menu".
Now I would like to create a function doing "init(a,b,c,d,e, ... ,n)" without having to create an overloaded function for every amount of arguments. Something that would work as below :

```cpp
class menu;
void init(menu);
// A is an unknown amount of "menu" elements;
void init(A){
    init(A);
}
```

Is this possible ? Thank you for any answer.

Comment: [Varargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#In_C)?

Comment: [Seek ye the parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack). That said, with all the same type passing in a temporary `std::vector` might be easier. eg: `void init(const std::vector<menu> & args);` and the `init({a,b,c,d,e,f,g});`

Comment: Not infinite. Your stack size is going to limit you.  Pass a reference to a collection, or pass a pointer and count, or pass a beginning and ending iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `std::vector<YourClass>` as an argument.